# Importing 3D model in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, 3d, xamarin.ios

I'm working on a Xamarin.ios app that requires a 3d model to be displayed throughout the app's runtime.

I'm hosting the model online, but it's not responding when I call it using its URI. I tried hosting it on Google Drive and glitch, but it still wouldn't let me use it.

Is there a method to bundle the model in the app and try to implement it? I know it can be done in Swift with NSBundle, but I'm using Xamarin in C#.

Comment: "3d model" could literally be a million different things.  There is no way for us to help you if you can't provide a more useful description of your problem

Comment: 3D Model, its formats are .dae, .gltf, .obj,. glb etc., hope it clears your doubt? and any 3d model is fine i dont mind a hand leg or a human i just need to load it into the app so i can display the miniatures on a map

Comment: You can use binding library to convert swift library https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-swift/